# Is it possible to access instance attributes separately in a class in python?

Tags: python, string, class, printing, attributes

In the below code if I create an instance of account as accnt and write accnt.owner, the program returns the memory location and not the value at the location. If i use **str**() method for the owner and balance I am able to obtain accnt.owner and accnt.balance values simultaneously.Is it possible to access both of them separately by just typing 
accnt.owner) \n
accnt.balance
without using print function?

```
class Account():

    def __init__(self,owner,balance):

        self.owner = owner
        self.balance = balance

accnt = ("Jose",100)
acct.owner----> Should output Jose
acct.balance---->Should output 100
```

Comment: "I create an instance of account as accnt and write accnt.owner, the program returns the memory location and not the value at the location" No, it does not. It prints 100. Your code would throw a `NameError` because `acct1` is not defined, actually. I *assume* You meant to do `accnt = Account("Jose", 100)`. Please provide a [mcve] and *describe the issue you are seeing as specifically as possible*. If that were the case, then `print(acct.owner)` would print "Jose" and `print(acct.balance)` would print "100"

Comment: Yes ,it should be accnt instead of accnt1

Comment: Due, your code *still* doesn't produce the output you claim. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Is it possible to return Jose and 100 by just typing accnt.owner and acct.balance without using the print function?

Comment: Yes. It is. You do it exactly like that. **What exactly is not working**?

Answer (score 0):

You are making a mistake, you have to indicate what class you are trying to instantiate:

```
class Account():

    def __init__(self, owner, balance):

        self.owner = owner
        self.balance = balance

accnt = ("Jose", 100) # <------------- This is wrong
accnt = Account("Jose",100) # <------- This is right
print(acct.owner)
print(acct.balance)
```

When you call a variable from the console, it gets printed, but from a code script, you must use `print()`.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to return Jose and 100 just by typing acct.owner and acct.balance without using print?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "return". If you want to send the value of `acct.owner` or `acct.balance`  to the console, you have to use `print()`.

Comment: It must be print

Comment: When you call a variable from the console, it gets printed (I added an example in the body of my answer), but from a code script, you must use print().

Comment: Thank you so much !!! Sorry if i was not that clear in my explanation of the problem!!!

Comment: No problem, hope I solve your doubt. If so, I'll appreciate you to select my answer